# Python why "asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: Exception is not set." here?

Tags: python, error-handling, python-asyncio

If you look at the code:

```
import asyncio
import datetime as dt


def get_results_or_none(tasks):
    results = []
    for task in tasks:
        if task.cancelled():
            print(task.get_name(), 'cancelled')
            results.append(None)
        else:
            if task.exception():
                print(task.get_name(), task.exception())
                results.append(None)
            else:
                print(task.get_name(), 'result', task.result())
                results.append(task.result())
    return results

async def main():

    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1), name='task1'),
        asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(3), name='task2'),
    ]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=2)

    return get_results_or_none(tasks)

start_time = dt.datetime.now()
task1, task2 = asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)

total_time = (dt.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()
print('lasted', total_time)

print(task1)
print(task2)
```

You can see that task2 is intentionally too long and causes timeout. I hoped that it will be enough to just retrieve task.exception(), but I get an output like this one:

```
task1 result None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/chk_invalid_state_error.py", line 31, in <module>
    task1, task2 = asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/algot/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/algot/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/user/project/chk_invalid_state_error.py", line 28, in main
    return get_results_or_none(tasks)
  File "/home/user/project/chk_invalid_state_error.py", line 12, in get_results_or_none
    if task.exception():
asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: Exception is not set.
```

What does it mean "asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: Exception is not set." in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thast error is raised if you check for exception in a task that is not done yet. (The call to `.wait()` timed out,but the task is still running).

You have to check if it is done, by calling the `.done()` method before calling `.exception()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.exception